# Event Handler for Input values and select option together

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, select, input

I have multiple input values with one select box option and validating and capturing all data based on `keypress` event. My issue is get all data input fields and select box and send using `keypress` event

[image: form fields]

To find all input values

```
var all_details = $('.myform'); 
var all_inputs = all_details.find('input');
var all_details_complete;
```

to get select values

```
var Country = $('#country').children("option:selected").val();
```

Adding few more additional data

```
  var some_data = {
       Country: Country,   //select box title displaying on image
       ReceiveOffers: 0
  };
```

Bind event! With following function I am getting all input field data except select box data. how can I add select `change` event and have tried following?

```
  all_inputs.on('keypress onchange', function() {                
            all_details_complete = false;
                _.each(all_inputs,  function (input) {
                    var $input = $(input);
                    all_inputs[$input.attr('name')] = $input.val();
                    if ($input.val() === '') all_details_complete = false;
                });
                if (all_details_complete) {
                     // post data successfully
               } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no `onchange` event, but a `change` event instead:

```
all_inputs.on('keypress change', function() {
  // Rest of the code here
};
```

However, for ease of standardization it's way easier to simply listen to the `input` event:

```
all_inputs.on('input', function() {
  // Rest of the code here
};
```

Comment: My bad about change event! you're right about input code.I have updated some details about select option. How about select option validation?